# How to make opentok working in ionic for ios?

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app, opentok, tokbox

I installed Cordova Plugin for OpenTok iOS in Ionic app
Using this 
cordova plugin add https://github.com/songz/cordova-plugin-opentok/

When i refer it using this

> < script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"
>   src="opentok.js">

in Index.html File
I get not found (404)

Answer (score 1):

This is normal behavior, because cordoba serves the plugin on the mobile device. When you debug on your web, cordoba is inactive, so you need to provide these dependencies yourself.